# Discord.py getting unexpected parentheses in output

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: T]

This is my discord.py bot. When I type `m!rate (person)` It sends me a text like this. However, I don't want the `('` and `',)` at the beginning and end of the message.

This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def rate(ctx, *member):
    if len(member) == 0:
        await ctx.send("You forgot to mention someone")
    else:
        value = random.randint(1,10)
        await ctx.send(f"I rate {member} {value}/10")
```

When I change it, the message works but the error doesn't. I can't find any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `*` in a parameter makes the function pass positional arguments into a tuple, hence the brackets. This is usually for when you want to unpack an arbitrary amount of arguments.

To fix it, just remove `*`, and also add a type for the parameter if you want:

```py
@client.command()
async def rate(ctx, member: discord.Member = None): # setting a default value of None
    if not member: # testing to see if the default value is None
        await ctx.send("You forgot to mention someone")
    else:
        value = random.randint(1,10)
        await ctx.send(f"I rate {member.mention} {value}/10")
```

---

**References:**

- [Using `*` in Python](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558)
- [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member)
- [`Member.mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.mention)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your bot to mention one person per command :

```py
@client.command()
async def rate(ctx, *member):
    if member:
        "".join(member)
        value = random.randint(1,10)
        for user in ctx.guild.members:
            if user.name.lower() == member.lower() or user.nick.lower() == member.lower():
               await ctx.send(f"I rate {user.mention} {value}/10")
            else:
              await ctx.send("Member not found!")   
    else:
        await ctx.send("You forgot to mention someone")
```

If you want your bot to mention multiple people per command :

```py
@client.command()
async def rate(ctx, *members):
    if members:
        embed = Discord.embed(color = discord.color.blue(), title = "title")
        count = 0
        for member in members:
            value = random.randint(1,10)
            for user in ctx.guild.members:
                if user.name.lower() == member.lower() or user.nick.lower() == member.lower():
                    embed.add_field(name = f"{user.mention}", value = f"I rate him {value}/10")
                    count += 1
        if count != 0:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Members not found!")
    else:
        await ctx.send("You forgot to mention someone")
```